# Convert 'parameter' to jQuery method

Tags: jquery, methods, eval

Is there a way to convert a parameter to a jQuery method, similar to eval in Javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var strFun = "hide";
var strParam = "slow";

var f=eval(strFun)("'" + strParam + "'");
$.globalEval(f);
var oo=$("#test");
oo.f();
</script>
```

Comment: @Connor, so was I. Had to read it a couple of times to understand what he was trying to do, but I think I figured it out ;)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but rather an anonymous function, since `eval` will evaluate the string when its passed to it.

```
(function($, undefined) {
    $.globalEval = function(name, fn, param) {
        if (typeof $.fn[name] === "undefined") {
            $.fn[name] = function(){
                var args = [].concat(
                    param,
                    [].slice.call(arguments));
                return this[fn].apply(this, args);
            };
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The above is used like this:

```
// Name of function to be called
var strFun = "hide";
// Params that should be passed, can be either array or string
var strParam = "slow";
// Call our plugin
$.globalEval("f", strFun, strParam);

// f() is now available for all elements
// Passing arguments here will add to the current params
// In this case, it will be the callback
$("div").f(function(){ /* Callback that is called when element is hidden */ });
```

The above isn't really useful, since you could just attach the anonymous function directly to `$.fn.f` and get the same result, but at least it gives you an idea of how it works.

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/UqHrF/)